# problem with rendering components wrapped in table

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

can anyone help me please im learning react courses and there is this exercise where i need to make components wrapped in a table but i get the error  i tried wrapping table in different things but it doesnt work but the task wont let me continiue unless i solve the error :
the application works well but in the console log there is a complete mess can anyone help with this ? and explain why ?

```
react_devtools_backend.js:4045 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a child of <tr>.
    at div
    at StatisticsLine (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:29:24)
    at tr
    at div
    at tbody
    at table
    at div
    at Statistics (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:45:13)
    at div
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:174:74)
overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend.js:4045
printWarning @ react-dom.development.js:67
error @ react-dom.development.js:43
validateDOMNesting @ react-dom.development.js:10081
createInstance @ react-dom.development.js:10181
completeWork @ react-dom.development.js:19464
completeUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:22815
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:22787
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:22707
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:22670
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22293
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:11327
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl @ react-dom.development.js:11322
flushSyncCallbackQueue @ react-dom.development.js:11309
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22420
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3756
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5889
react_devtools_backend.js:4045 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <tr> cannot appear as a child of <div>.
    at tr
    at div
    at tbody
    at table
    at div
    at Statistics (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:45:13)
    at div
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:174:74)
overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend.js:4045
printWarning @ react-dom.development.js:67
error @ react-dom.development.js:43
validateDOMNesting @ react-dom.development.js:10081
createInstance @ react-dom.development.js:10181
completeWork @ react-dom.development.js:19464
completeUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:22815
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:22787
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:22707
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:22670
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22293
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:11327
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl @ react-dom.development.js:11322
flushSyncCallbackQueue @ react-dom.development.js:11309
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22420
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3756
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5889
react_devtools_backend.js:4045 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <p> cannot appear as a child of <tr>.
    at p
    at tr
    at div
    at tbody
    at table
    at div
    at Statistics (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:45:13)
    at div
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:174:74)
```

jsx code :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const StatisticsLine = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{props.text}{props.value}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
const Statistics = (props) =>{
 if(props.allClicks.length === 0){
   return (
     <div>
       <h1>There is no feedback</h1>
     </div>
   )
 }

  return (
    <div>
     
  
     <h1>statistics</h1>
     <table>
       <tbody>
         <div>
     <tr><StatisticsLine text="good " value={props.good}/></tr>
     <tr><StatisticsLine text="neutral " value={props.neutral}/></tr>
     <tr><StatisticsLine text="bad " value={props.bad}/></tr>
     <tr><p>all {props.good+ props.neutral  + props.bad}</p></tr>
     <tr><p>average {(props.good+ props.neutral  + props.bad)/3}</p></tr>
     <tr><p>positive :{(props.good+ props.neutral  + props.bad)*props.good/100}%</p></tr>
     </div>
     </tbody>
     </table>
    
     
     </div>
  )
 }

const App = () => {
  const [good, setGood] = useState(0)
  const [neutral, setNeutral] = useState(0)
  const [bad, setBad] = useState(0)
  const [allClicks, setAll] = useState([])
  const handleGood = () => {
   setAll(allClicks.concat(" "))
    setGood(good + 1)
  }
const handleNeutral = () =>{
  setAll(allClicks.concat(" "))
  setNeutral(neutral + 1)
}
  const handleBad = () =>{
    setAll(allClicks.concat(" "))
    setBad(bad+1)
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>give feedback</h1>
      <button onClick={()=>handleGood()}>good</button>
     <button onClick={() =>handleNeutral()}>neutral</button>
     <button onClick={() =>handleBad()}>bad</button>
     <Statistics  good={good} neutral={neutral} bad={bad} allClicks={allClicks} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Please remove the `<div>` after `<tbody>` and `</div>` before `</tbody>`

Comment: this didnt help

Comment: In each `tr` tag, add `td` tag. and move the content inside `tr` tag to `td` tag

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const StatisticsLine = (props) => {
  return (
    <td>
      {props.text}
      {props.value}
    </td>
  );
};

const Statistics = (props) => {
  if (props.allClicks.length === 0) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>There is no feedback</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>statistics</h1>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <StatisticsLine text="good " value={props.good} />
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <StatisticsLine text="neutral " value={props.neutral} />
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <StatisticsLine text="bad " value={props.bad} />
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>all {props.good + props.neutral + props.bad}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>average {(props.good + props.neutral + props.bad) / 3}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              positive :
              {((props.good + props.neutral + props.bad) * props.good) / 100}%
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [good, setGood] = useState(0);
  const [neutral, setNeutral] = useState(0);
  const [bad, setBad] = useState(0);
  const [allClicks, setAll] = useState([]);
  const handleGood = () => {
    setAll(allClicks.concat(" "));
    setGood(good + 1);
  };
  const handleNeutral = () => {
    setAll(allClicks.concat(" "));
    setNeutral(neutral + 1);
  };
  const handleBad = () => {
    setAll(allClicks.concat(" "));
    setBad(bad + 1);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>give feedback</h1>
      <button onClick={() => handleGood()}>good</button>
      <button onClick={() => handleNeutral()}>neutral</button>
      <button onClick={() => handleBad()}>bad</button>
      <Statistics
        good={good}
        neutral={neutral}
        bad={bad}
        allClicks={allClicks}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Please remove  `<div>`  tag   from  `<tbody>`

Comment: and `<div>` from  `<tr>` and add  `<td>` tag